# how to increase kernel timer frequency

Tags: linux, timer, linux-device-driver

I wanted to measure the time taken between some statements in my driver code(Linux version 3.4).
I am using **jiffies** to record the start and end of the counter and then converting to milliseconds.

By default the **HZ** value is defined as **128** which gives the precision of only **7ms**(ie for each increment in the counter by **1** ,the corresponding time will be incremented by **7ms**)

If I increase the value of **HZ** to **1000**,I can get a precision of **1ms**.

I should modify some statements in kernel code.

So far I have tried these things but in vain

In `arch/arm/include/asm/param.h`,

I replaced

`#define HZ CONFIG_HZ`

with

`#define HZ 256`.

Are there any other statements to be modified?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [the timestamp counter for precise measurements](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-1#chp-7-sect-1.2)?

> If you need to measure very short time intervals or you need extremely high precision in your figures, you can resort to platform-dependent resources, a choice of precision over portability... CPU manufacturers introduced a way to count clock cycles as an easy and reliable way to measure time lapses. Therefore, most modern processors include a counter register that is steadily incremented once at each clock cycle. Nowadays, this clock counter is the only reliable way to carry out high-resolution timekeeping tasks.